# Mp4 Video not displayed with AngularJS with Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video

I am having difficulties understanding why my video is not displayed if I used a AngularJS variable for src. If I use directly src="img/test1.mp4", it works. And if I want to display the {{camera[0].video}} in HTML, I have "test1" correctly displayed. Thanks for your help. Here is part of the code :

```js
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {

 $scope.camera = [{
      id: "1",
      video: "test1"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      video: "test2"
    }];
  });
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="appCtrl">
     <video width="250" height="200" controls autoplay>
     <source src="img/{{camera[0].video}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you extend your code snippet, so it is runable? At the moment an error message does orcur, when I pressed "Run code snippet".

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>

var app = angular.module('App', [])

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.path = "img/test1.mp4";
 $scope.changePath = function() {
  $scope.path = "img/test2.mp4";
  $scope.$apply;
 }
 
});

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="App">
 <div ng-controller="appCtrl"> 
  <div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changePath()">Change Video</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <video width="480" height="280" controls autoplay>
    <source ng-src="{{path}}" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to have test1.mp4 and test2.mp4 videos in img folder to run it correctly. My problem now is that if by pressing the change video button I want to change the video path, the current video is still running and the path change is not taken into account. Thanks for your help.